# Not able show Load more button coditionally in react and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to only show the "Load More" button when I have extra documents to show on my React and Firebase website.
Right now, I'm fetching only 2 documents from a firestore and I want to show the "Load More" button when I have more than 2 documents in my firestore. If I only have 2 or fewer than 2 documents in my firestore, I don't want to show the "Load More" button.
And I want to hide the "Load More" button after fetching all the documents that I have on the firestore.

Anyone, please help me with this!

useCollection Hook:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
// firebase import
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  limit,
  onSnapshot,
  orderBy,
  query,
  startAfter,
  where,
} from "firebase/firestore"

import { db } from "../firebase/config"

export const useCollection = (c, _q, _l, _o) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  // if we don't use a ref --> infinite loop in useEffect
  // _query is an array and is "different" on every function call
  const q = useRef(_q).current
  const o = useRef(_o).current

  useEffect(() => {
    let ref = collection(db, c)
    if (q) {
      ref = query(ref, where(...q))
    }
    if (o) {
      ref = query(ref, orderBy(...o))
    }
    if (_l) {
      ref = query(ref, limit(_l))
    }

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      const results = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (doc) => {
          results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          setError("could not fetch the data")
        }
      )
      // update state
      setDocuments(results)
      setIsLoading(false)
      setError(null)
    })

    // unsubscribe on unmount
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  const fetchMore = async (doc) => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const q = query(
      collection(db, c),
      orderBy(...o),
      startAfter(doc.createdAt),
      limit(_l)
    )
    const newDocuments = await getDocs(q)
    updateState(newDocuments)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  const updateState = (docs) => {
    if (!docs.empty) {
      const tempPosts = []
      docs.forEach((document) => {
        tempPosts.push({
          id: document.id,
          ...document.data(),
        })
      })
      setDocuments([...documents, ...tempPosts])
    }
  }

  return { documents, fetchMore, error, isLoading }
}
```

SolutionComments.js (In this file I'm showing the "Load More Comments" button)

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

import { useCollection } from "../../hooks/useCollection"

import Comment from "./Comment"
import CommentForm from "./CommentForm"

const SolutionComments = () => {
  const [activeComment, setActiveComment] = useState(null)
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { documents, fetchMore, isLoading } = useCollection(
    `solutions/${id}/comments`,
    null,
    2,
    ["createdAt", "desc"]
  )

  const fetchMoreComments = () => {
    fetchMore(documents[documents.length - 1])
  }

  return (
    <div className="mt-10">
      <CommentForm docID={id} />
      <div>
        {documents &&
          documents.map((comment) => (
            <Comment
              key={comment.id}
              comment={comment}
              replies={comment.replies}
              activeComment={activeComment}
              setActiveComment={setActiveComment}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
      {documents.length > 2 && (
        <button onClick={fetchMoreComments} className="text-white bg-purple-500">
          {!isLoading ? "Load More Comments!" : "Loading..."}
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SolutionComments
```

Comment: The use-case sounds clear enough. What is your question for us about the code you shared? Which specific line isn't doing what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have a mechanism for automatically telling you how many documents are in a query. You will need to manage that aggregate count yourself. Then you could fetch that aggregate count and use that to determine whether to show a load more button or not.

However this is harder than it sounds. And most modern apps we don't use load more buttons rather we use infinite scroll.

To be honest, it has never been efficient or smart to show a result set count in an app. The fact that people have done it in the past doesn't mean that it is the right thing to do today. It might have made sense when you had small databases, typically running off of a desktop database. But in a cloud-based solution with millions of documents and millions of users, and complex queries, knowing how many documents are in a result set is a very hard problem to solve.